# Adapt google docs script to google sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a function "myFunk()" that works beautifully in google docs. It basically searches a sheet for the fields with ## and replaces them with user input. But when I try to run it in sheets after changing the functions I get "Cannot find function replaceText in object." What am I missing?

```js
function myFunk() {
  // Display a dialog box for each field you need information for.
  var documentProperties = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties();
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  //var response = ui.prompt('Enter Name', 'Enter owners person's name', ui.ButtonSet.OK);
  var nameResponse = ui.prompt("Enter the name of the document OWNER");
  var salesperson = nameResponse.getResponseText();
  var documentProperties = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties();
  var date = new Date();
  var htmlDlg = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("HTML_myHtml")
    .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
    .setWidth(200)
    .setHeight(150);

  var modal = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  modal.showModalDialog(htmlDlg, "Document Classification");

  //Get Current Document ID
  var documentId = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId();
  console.log(documentId);

  //Get the document body as a variable
  var body = SpreadsheetApp.openById(documentId).getDataRange().getValues();
  console.log(body);

  //Insert the entries into the document
  body.replaceText("##OWNER##", nameResponse.getResponseText());

  //AddValuesFromModal();
}
```

```html
<form id="docType">
<select id="selectDocumentType" name="documentClass">
  <option value="PUBLIC">Public</option>
  <option value="INTERNAL">Internal</option>
  <option value="CONFIDENTIAL">Confidential</option>
  <option value="SECRET">Secret</option>
</select>

<hr/>
 <input type="button" onClick="formSubmit();" value="Submit" />
</form>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <script>a
    function formSubmit(){
    Submit();
    }
   
    
    function Submit() {
    var selectedValue = $('#selectDocumentType').val();
    console.log(selectedValue);
      google.script.run
        .withSuccessHandler(closeIt)
        .AddValuesFromModal(selectedValue);
      };
      
    function closeIt(){
      google.script.host.close();
    };
    </script>
```

Comment: What your missing is that the structure of a Google Document and a Google Spreadsheet is entirely different.  In the current script the variable body is a 2 dimensional array of data and it does not have  a replaceText() method. [Here's a list of Array Methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Spreadsheet has no body section, as found in a document, instead it has Ranges, which are grids of data representing cells in the spreadsheet you wish to operate on.  Instead of trying to work with the *values* of the Range, as in your current code, you can work with the Range object itself.

The solution is to select the relevant Range with getDataRange(), but do not call getValues().  Instead, create a TextFinder object that can search and replace data within the Range.

It should look something like this:

```
var range = SpreadsheetApp.openById(documentId).getDataRange();
var finder = range.createTextFinder('##OWNER##');
finder.replaceAllWith(nameResponse.getResponseText());
```

which can likely be shortened to a one-liner:

```
SpreadsheetApp.openById(documentId).getDataRange().createTextFinder('##OWNER##').replaceAllWith(nameResponse.getResponseText());
```

See:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#createTextFinder(String)

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder#replaceWith(String)